# How do I pass information into getView of a custom ArrayAdapter?

Tags: android, android-adapter

I have the following class in my application:

```
public class Player implements Parcelable {
    private String name;
    private int playerColor;
    private int[] scores;
    ...
}
```

How do I tell the getView method of my ArrayAdapter which element of the scores array to display in the associated listview?  I want to display in the ListView the player.name field, as well as a particular element of the player.scores array, based on information from the activity.

```
public class PlayerGameAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Player> {
private ArrayList<Player> entries;
private Activity activity;

 public PlayerGameAdapter(Activity a, int viewResourceId, ArrayList<Player> entries) {
    super(a, viewResourceId, entries);
    this.entries = entries;
    this.activity = a;
}

public static class ViewHolder {
    public Button buttonName;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View v = convertView;
    ViewHolder holder;
    if (v == null) {
        LayoutInflater vi =
                (LayoutInflater) activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        v = vi.inflate(R.layout.listview_row_player_game, null);
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.buttonName = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.buttonGamePlayerListName);
        v.setTag(holder);
    } else
        holder = (ViewHolder) v.getTag();

    final MiniGolfPlayer player = entries.get(position);
    if (player != null) {
        holder.buttonName.setText(player.getName() + " - " + player.scores[ELEMENT]);
    }
    return v;
}
```

}

Comment: are you displaying the players info in the list view. or you are displaying the player results. and you wonna to change that player from time to time.

Comment: Both.  I want to display their name and their score for a particular round, as determined in the activity.

Comment: Can you edit your question to include PlayerGameAdapter constructor?

Comment: also include the line you initialise the PlayerGameAdapter in it.

Comment: ok this is enough I will answer

Comment: Is that what r u looking for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add position variable to your Player Class.

```
public class Player implements Parcelable {
    private String name;
    private int playerColor;
    private int[] scores;
    private int position; // also add the get and set methods
}
```

On your activity you can change the position of the score you want to show for every player individually.

```
((Player)entries.get(0)).setPosition(AnyValueYouWant);
((Player)entries.get(1)).setPosition(AnotherValue);
```

Then notify your adapter to refresh listview:

```
PlayerGameAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Does that work for you. or you expect something else.

Comment: I am wondering thought. What is your app logic. and on what bases you change the score displayed?